# How to Change Maven repository to inbuilt repository in same network

Tags: maven

In our project we need to setup a repository in a remote machine and I need to point to that repository. I have tried changing settings.xml.

But that didn't work. Then I added repository directly in pom.

This works. But still I am seeing the artifacts are downloaded from central repository. When I checked the effective pom, I am seeing that central repository is been mentioned along with mentioned internal repository

I dont need artifacts to be downloaded from central repository. Instead I need to download from my remote repository. How can I achieve it. TIA :)

Comment: Best is to install a repository manager (Nexus) on your remote machine and configure your settings based on the documentation: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Answer (score 0):

You can force Maven to use a single repository by having it mirror all repository requests. The repository must contain all of the desired artifacts, or be able to proxy the requests to other repositories. This setting is most useful when using an internal company repository with the Maven Repository Manager to proxy external requests.

To achieve this, set mirrorOf to *.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
      <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

more details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)